# implementing apply function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

I have been trying to implement apply function in Rcpp so far the code looks like this

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector apply(NumericMatrix x,int dim,Function f){
  NumericVector output;
  if(dim==1){
   for(int i=0;i<x.nrow();i++){
     output[i]=f(x(i,_));
   }    
  }
  else if(dim==2){
   for(int i=0;i<x.ncol();i++){
     output[i]=f(x(_,i));
   }
  }
  return(output);
}
```

but i'm getting an error "cannot convert SEXP to double in assignment" in line 6 and 11. Is there any way to convert the value returned by an arbitrary function to double? also is there a sugar function for the apply function.

Comment: I also tried to explicitly convert the returned value to double but that doesn't seem to work as well

Comment: `as<double>` is how you do explicit conversion to a `double`

Comment: Another problem of your code is that `output` is not created to the correct size. So even if you added `as<double>` in the two places, you would not get what you want, and as a bonus you'd get undefined behavior as you assign out of bounds and Rcpp does not do bounds checks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no sugar function for `apply`. The easiest way of doing what you want is to call `as<double>`, i.e.:

```
output[i]=as<double>(f(x(i,_)));
```

You could also embed this in a type that would call `as` for you, something like:

```
template <typename T>
class F {
public: 
  F( SEXP f_) : f(f_){}

  inline T operator()(NumericVector x){
    return as<T>(f(x)) ;  
  }

private:
  Function f ;
} ;
```

so that you could do:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector apply_cpp(NumericMatrix x,int dim,F<double> f){
  if(dim==1){
    NumericVector output(x.nrow());
    for(int i=0;i<x.nrow();i++){
      output[i]=f(x(i,_));
    } 
    return output ;
  }
  else {
    NumericVector output(x.ncol());

    for(int i=0;i<x.ncol();i++){
      output[i]=f(x(_,i));
    }  
    return output ;
  }
}
```

The `F` template from above assumes that the function takes a `NumericVector` and returns something that can be converted to a `double`. You could also embed type information about both inputs and outputs. Something like this (expressed in C++11):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class F {
public: 
  F( SEXP f_) : f(f_){}

  inline T operator()(Args... args){
    return as<T>(f(args...)) ;  
  }

private:
  Function f ;
} ;
```

Then the signature would become:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector apply_cpp(NumericMatrix x,int dim,F<double,NumericVector> f){
```

Comment: Thank you @Romain Francois, This is a more generalized solution :)

Comment: Well, this is actually answering the question, instead of throwing in vaguely related stuff.

Comment: Also I am not clear about the Function object. Is it similar to function pointers? can you give me pointers to learn what is Function objects in rcpp.

Comment: `Function` is an Rcpp api class that wraps an R function object and allows you to call the function with C++ `operator()`.

Answer (score 4):

The answers are, in order, "yes" and "yes", and you may want to read the "Rcpp Introduction" which contains the following `lapply()` example:

```
R> src <- '
+   Rcpp::List input(data);
+   Rcpp::Function f(fun);
+   Rcpp::List output(input.size());
+   std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), f);
+   output.names() = input.names();
+   return output;
+   '
R> cpp_lapply <- cxxfunction(signature(data = "list", fun = "function"),
+    src, plugin = "Rcpp")
```

This was written for inline rather than Rcpp Attributes because that is how we rolled back in the day.  We have more apply-alike functions in other examples and unit tests...

You have not specified what arguments your function `f()` takes and returns which makes fixing your question a little trickier.

Comment: Thank you for the the answer :), The argument for the function is a numeric vector and it returns a double value.